# Why is overriding both the global new operator and the class-specific operator not ambiguous behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, new-operator

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    //class-specific
    Foo operator+(Foo& rhs)
    {
       return Foo(); //Just return a temporary
    }

    void* operator new(size_t sd)
    {
        return malloc(sd);
    }
};

//global
Foo operator+(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs)
{
    return Foo();
}

void* operator new(size_t sd)
{
    return malloc(sd);
}
```

This code will not compile, stating the call is ambiguous because it matches two operators:

```
Foo a, b;
a + b;
```

But this one with the new operator compiles just fine, and will call the class-specific one.

```
Foo* a = new Foo();
```

Why doesn't it result in a compile error? Does the compiler treat the new operator differently? (Any citation to the standard would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't it result in a compile error? Does the compiler treat the new operator differently? (Any citation to the standard would be appreciated)

Regarding the precedence between global `new` and class specific `new`, the reference says [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

> As described in allocation function, the C++ program may provide global and class-specific replacements for these functions. If the new-expression begins with the optional :: operator, as in ::new T or ::new T[n], class-specific replacements will be ignored (the function is looked up in global scope). **Otherwise, if T is a class type, lookup begins in the class scope of T.**

So class specific `new` has priority.

Regarding the overload of `+`, you can either have the member overload **or** the global overload (usually as a `friend` of the class) but not both because of the ambiguity it produces.

Answer (score 5):

The class' `operator new` is always preferred if defined:

> #### [`[expr.new]/9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#9)
>
> If the *new-expression* begins with a unary ​`::`​ operator, the allocation function's name is looked up in the global scope. Otherwise, if the allocated type is a class type `T` or array thereof, the allocation function's name is looked up in the scope of `T`. If this lookup fails to find the name, or if the allocated type is not a class type, the allocation function's name is looked up in the global scope.

It can be tricky to read: if the *new-expression* does not begins with `::` and the *allocated type* is a class type, then `new` is looked up in the class' scope.

Answer (score 4):

Your global `new` operator has no direct relation to the class `Foo`. A class specific `new` has precedence over the global `new`. There is no ambiguity.

Your `operator+` does specifically relate to the class `Foo`. There is no precedence between the operator defined outside and the one defined inside the class. Thus you get ambiguity.